# How to clean up subdivided cube for extrusion?

Tags: mesh

[image]

Blender 4.0 screenshot of scaled up cube subdivided as a whole 5x then one side of panels aces split on one side only.

The one side only subdivision vertices were linked together via **f** cmd. But all the other lines that are unselectable appear in the picture when trying to extrude vertically the faces (2nd gen cut)
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org). Photos are harder to read because we have to look past external interferences (like reflections, smudges or Moiré patterns) and guess if we are looking at hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connections, a software level issue like driver malfunction or glitch, or actual artifacts or issues with the model itself.

Comment: The problem is just to the right and above the cursor. I simply cannot select the lines in question.

Comment: To take a screenshot in Blender use Blender's own Window > Save Screenshot menu rather than an external application.